# IIS 8.5 Windows authentication app not working

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have several apps running on a IIS 8.5 and I'm quite sure I have all the necessary features installed.
When I try to login the app my user doesn't work, I tried with other users with same result. I think the app is not looking into the Active Directory server because I get no errors or logs in the app folder, I only have 401 (401 0 and 401 1) errors in the IIS log.

```
    2017-07-26 08:42:53 10.101.16.195 GET /WebHostWinAuth/ wtrealm=urn%3aidsrv3&wctx=WsFedOwinState%3d2cw409_89M-Nz-vqfNi_cx3e2yfn1D95OvHx8vuwRQKRO7LgEANQTJqJjpvpvOrTqF87CLTdvkxRVtF5aOadAQOLSm7v6WFMTa_Y976-0eEfovVtyxmHqGsxY6YKSYXOsJq2yqCp7O_PKmfAf73UMC0ewTi8N0b9ZXt7cbhgJ1egONt7Ciqt2dGJDLwUCM7fYB-9s78xWApt8ZNRXBiWQQvi1jtPxqFgaZsQ6NuMqFU&wa=wsignin1.0 443 - 10.101.16.195 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/59.0.3071.115+Safari/537.36 - 401 0 0 18
    2017-07-26 08:43:04 10.101.16.195 GET /WebHostWinAuth/ wtrealm=urn%3aidsrv3&wctx=WsFedOwinState%3d2cw409_89M-Nz-vqfNi_cx3e2yfn1D95OvHx8vuwRQKRO7LgEANQTJqJjpvpvOrTqF87CLTdvkxRVtF5aOadAQOLSm7v6WFMTa_Y976-0eEfovVtyxmHqGsxY6YKSYXOsJq2yqCp7O_PKmfAf73UMC0ewTi8N0b9ZXt7cbhgJ1egONt7Ciqt2dGJDLwUCM7fYB-9s78xWAptgnin1.0 443 - 10.101.16.195 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/59.0.3071.115+Safari/537.36 - 401 1 3221225581 2
    2017-07-26 08:43:21 10.101.16.195 GET /WebHostWinAuth/ wtrealm=urn%3aidsrv3&wctx=WsFedOwinState%3d2cw409_89M-Nz-vqfNi_cx3e2yfn1D95OvHx8vuwRQKRO7LgEANQTJqJjpvpvOrTqF87CLTdvkxRVtF5aOadAQOLSm7v6WFMTa_Y976-0eEfovVtyxmHqGsxY6YKSYXOsJq2yqCp7O_PKmfAf73UMC0ewTi8N0b9ZXt7cbhgJ1egONt7Ciqt2dGJDLwUCM7fYB-9s78xWApt8ZNRXBiWQQvi1jtPxqFgaZsQ6NuMqFU&wa=wsignin1.0 443 - 10.101.16.195 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/59.0.3071.115+Safari/537.36 - 401 1 3221225581 38ZNRXBiWQQvi1jtPxqFgaZsQ6NuMqFU&wa=wsignin1.0 443 - 10.101.16.195 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/59.0.3071.115+Safari/537.36 - 401 1 3221225581 2
    2017-07-26 08:43:18 10.101.16.195 GET /WebHostWinAuth/ wtrealm=urn%3aidsrv3&wctx=WsFedOwinState%3d2cw409_89M-Nz-vqfNi_cx3e2yfn1D95OvHx8vuwRQKRO7LgEANQTJqJjpvpvOrTqF87CLTdvkxRVtF5aOadAQOLSm7v6WFMTa_Y976-0eEfovVtyxmHqGsxY6YKSYXOsJq2yqCp7O_PKmfAf73UMC0ewTi8N0b9ZXt7cbhgJ1egONt7Ciqt2dGJDLwUCM7fYB-9s78xWApt8ZNRXBiWQQvi1jtPxqFgaZsQ6NuMqFU&wa=wsi
```

I also tried to create a simple app, just a simple html with windows authentication with same result, so it is not an app problem, it is about IIS configuration.

The user (and Active Directory, e.g. example.server.root) domain is not the same than the local machine server (different.host.com), does this matter? I have accessed this computer remotely using my user, so this computer should have access to the active directory domain right?

I have tried:

- Different users
- Providers
- Different web site
- Other certificate
- Edit Web Site anonymous auth to app pool identity
- Add permissions to the web site folder (even with everyone)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people with the same issue, this is exactly wath was happening:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate

I can't add or modify registers, so the only solution has been access the machine from another virtual machine, and work with both at the same time. Far from being a proper solution, but at least I can continue my job.

Answer (score 1):

This is what really happened. The windows user was an admin, and it has no additional information in ActivaDirectory (no email or surname). The software was expecting a "non null" on those fields, so the login failed.